# Unhandled exception at 0x50E2DF58 (msvcp120d.dll)

Tags: c++, io

I'm trying to read from a binary file into structs. The error is thrown when the program exits. I breakpointed it and the error comes up after return 0 is executed.

When I run the program it actually displays the results. It does not crash until after the `system("pause")`

This is the actual error: Unhandled exception at 0x50E2DF58 (msvcp120d.dll) in struct reader.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x007AB1EC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct user{
    string name;
};

int main(){
    fstream file("file.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    user users[5];

    for (size_t i = 0; !file.eof(); i++)
    {
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&users[i]), sizeof(user));
    }

    file.close();
    size_t size = (sizeof(users) / sizeof(user));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << users[i].name << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ strings are complex data structures that include pointers to heap allocated memory.  You can't write and read them as binary data. They need to be properly serialized.  Your code will work if you change from C++ strings to a plain C-like char[N] for some constant value of N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return from your function, the destructor for each element of the `users` array is executed.

The `users` array contains 5 `user` objects, each of which contain a `std::string`.

`std::string` objects abstract heap allocated memory, which they use as a buffer to contain each character of the string they contain.

When you perform a binary write onto each element of the `users` array, you're setting the internal pointer(s) of the `std::string` instances to garbage.  When their destructors are called they then try to read through a garbage pointer, and/or free a garbage pointer.

At any rate, it's bad business.

To fix this problem, you need to implement some mechanism for actually serializing/deserializing the strings, just copying the raw bytes of the objects isn't going to cut it.

Comment: So might as well use a serializing library instead of what I was doing?

Comment: either that, or actually write code that reads into strings properly